# Robolectric Exception when view.performLongClick()

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a special need to write a test like below:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LongClickTest {
    @Test
    public void testPerformLongClick() {
        View view = new View(Robolectric.application);
        view.performLongClick();
    }
}
```

But it gives me the following errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:4154)
    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4123)
    at org.robobinding.widget.view.OnLongClickAttributeTest.longClickOnView(OnLongClickAttributeTest.java:34)
    at org.robobinding.widget.view.OnLongClickAttributeTest.givenBoundAttribute_whenLongClickOnView_thenEventReceived(OnLongClickAttributeTest.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:250)
        ...
```

I checked a similar test in Robolectric itself org.robolectric.shadows.ViewTest.performLongClick_shouldClickOnView, but i could not figure out why the one in Robolectric works and mine does not. By the way, i am using Robolectric 2.3.

Appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Cheng

Comment: Could you post the exact code that you are trying to run?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks. I have updated the content. If you run the test, you will get the same error. My test is more than this, but that is the part i am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You should be doing shadowOf(view).performLongClick.</s>

Also, that's probably not the best way to create the View you're interested in. Try

```
view = new View(new Activity());
```

or use a LayoutInflater.

The stacktrace indicates that the problem is with creating the context menu which is the default behaviour for the long click. The reason why the robo test works and yours fail is that they override the onLongClickListener. 
So just try something like this:

```
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               return true;
           }
        });
```

The key thing there is to return true, so that the context menu is not invoked, if you want to be testing this in isolation.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. But in Robolectric 2.3, there is not such method performLongClick on ShadowView. If you check this test [link](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ViewTest.java) the method performLongClick_shouldClickOnView() at line 178. You will see Robolectric is doing the same. I am not interested in using Activity or LayoutInflater as i said i got a special need, testing a framework not a n app.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't paying attention to the stacktrace, my bad. I've updated my answer, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I found it too by debugging. I will leave yours as the answer. I posted the same question in Robolectric google group without answer for some time. that's why i posted here. Thanks again for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing exactly the context menu. It is called from a line of a listView. That's how I did it (it's in Kotlin):

```
    val activity = buildActivity(MyActivity::class.java).create().get()
    val customView = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
        .inflate(R.layout.custom_xml, activity.my_list_view, false)
        as MyCustomView

    val linearLayout = activity.my_list_view.parent as LinearLayout
    linearLayout.addView(customView)
```

Now performClick works. I just need to learn how to get de context menu to test this one!

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: The null pointer is a side effect of how the view is being instantiated